# Ninject Singleton Factory

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a interface that is binded  to a class. Everything work like excepted. I want to create the class with a constructor injection without passing my kernel everywhere. I want to have a singleton factory for these propose. How can i create one without using the ninject.extensions.factory library.

Comment: Please provide your app type (exe/WF/Service/MVC) - there are some utils relevant for each technology?

Comment: Its WPF, but i need it inside a data model class not inside any viewmodel or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a factory but without using the Factory Extension (not sure why, it's exactly what you need here I think) you can do something like the following:

```
public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    // allows us to Get things from the kernel, but not add new bindings etc.
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public FooFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public IFoo CreateFoo()
    {
        return this.resolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>();
    }

    // or if you want to specify a value at runtime...

    public IFoo CreateFoo(string myArg)
    {
        return this.resolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>(new ConstructorArgument("myArg", myArg));
    }
}

public class Foo : IFoo { ... }

public class NeedsFooAtRuntime
{
    public NeedsFooAtRuntime(IFooFactory factory)
    {
        this.foo = factory.CreateFoo("test");
    }
}

Bind<IFooFactory>().To<FooFactory>();
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
```

The Factory Extension just does all of that work for you at runtime though. You only need to define the factory interface and the extension creates the implementation dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class NinjectKernelSingleton
{
    private static YourKernel _kernel;

    public static YourKernel Kernel
    {
        get { return _kernel ?? (_kernel = new YourKernel()); }
    }

}

public class YourKernel
{
    private IKernel _kernel;
    public YourKernel()
    {
        _kernel = InitKernel();
    }

    private IKernel InitKernel()
    {
        //Ninject init logic goes here
    }

    public T Resolve<T>() 
    {
        return _kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not suggest going this route, as it is an example of the service locator anti-pattern: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: @Bryan J. Ross If these is a anti-pattern, you say i should pass my reference everywhere ? These kind of sucks.

Comment: I will use the ninject.extensions.factory library instead.

Comment: @Abc: If you have something that needs to be passed everywhere, usually that's a sign that your application structure needs to be re-thought, as that is now essentially global data.